# Exponential time algorithms

Tags: time-complexity

Wiki define [Polynomial time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_time#Polynomial_time) as fallow:

> An algorithm is said to be of polynomial time if its running time is
>   upper bounded by a [polynomial expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_expression) in the size of the input for
>   the algorithm, i.e., $T(n) = O(n^k)$ for some constant $k$

I understand that in general speaking the difference between **Polynomial time** and [Exponential time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_time#Exponential_time) is that exponential function grows strictly faster than any polynomial function, asymptotically([reference](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/18743/10572)).

I am trying to understand the core definition of **Exponential time**.

1. What elements will make one algorithm to run in **Exponential time**?
2. What change do I need to do in the **polynomial expression** to make it **Exponential time**?(By *it* I am referring to the algorithm definition in the beginning of the question)

Comment: 1. Do exponentially many things. 2. Use the polynomial as the power of a base > 1.

Comment: I don't understand your second question. Polynomials are polynomials; exponentials are exponentials. Asking what you need to change to make a polynomial into an exponential is like asking what you need to change to make a logarithm into a cosine.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Will there be exponential time functions if P = NP? How can you define an exponential time function in terms of polynomial expression?

Comment: Exponential functions will certainly still exist if P=NP. There are probably still problems that'll take exponential time even if P=NP, though none spring to mind immediately. An exponential function can be defined in terms of a polynomial, but that polynomial must be infinitely long - you may want to look up Taylor Expansions if you're interested in this.

Comment: @ymbirtt Even the easiest version of the [time hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem) says that there is no polynomial-time algorithm for any EXPTIME-complete problem. That's an unconditional result: it doesn't depend on the assumption that P$\neq$NP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. There's no easy answer for this one, though there are signs to look out for. Examining every possible subset of a set, for instance, is exponential - so if I had a set of integers $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$, and wanted to check every subset of these to see if they sum to $0$, I'd have to consider exactly $2^n$ subsets, which makes this method exponential time. Several different traps can make an algorithm exponential time, however, so rather than looking out for broad categories, analyse algorithms on a case-by-case basis.
2. If an algorithm takes $n^2$ steps to complete, then it's polynomial. If it takes $2^n$ steps, it's exponential. The difference is the position of the $n$. If something is $O(n^m)$ for $n> 1$, $m>0$, then it's polynomial in $n$ for fixed $m$, but exponential in $m$ for fixed $n$.

Comment: Careful. The function $n^m$ isn't polynomial in $n$ unless $m$ is a constant. And, if $m$ *is* a constant, it doesn't make sense to say that the function is exponential in that constant.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'll clarify that.

Answer (score 4):

Often you get an exponential time brute-force algorithm when you consider a problem, and enumerate its whole search space. Typically, you'd think of subset problems (in SAT, you would choose a subset of variables set to true), permutation problems (in TSP, every tour is a permutation of the cities), and partition problems (in graph coloring, you are trying to partition the vertices into color classes). Or consider sorting even: there are $n!$ permutations of $n$ integers. Go through every permutation, and check if it is sorted. Silly (and slow), but it works.

Comment: Though note that $O(n!)$ is even worse than $O(k^n)$. If you're still trying to learn about time complexity, this could be a useful thing to prove to yourself.